# function run in the background c++

Tags: c++, function

I created a function that run in while(1) and return an integer, I want to turn this function in background and recover their return.

who can help me please!

here is my function:

```
int my_fct() {
    while(1) {
        int result = 1;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: For the sake of readability, you can simplify your function to: `int my_fct() { return 1; }`

Comment: You should read something about pthreads. Threads can't be explained in a post. Read:

https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/

Comment: Can you include the function and the code where the function is being called from? And what exactly do you mean bu "turn this function in background"?

Comment: If you can use c++11, I'd recommend using the built-in threads. Otherwise, pthreads or boost::thread. Just create a thread to do what you need done in the background, and when you need the result, call join() on the thread before trying to use it.

Comment: @anbuselvan pthreads is for unix but my system Windows

Comment: @HarshilSharma exactly my function checks a field in the database and return 1 if my condition is verified else return 0 and I call this function in the main

Comment: then you can use  std::async and std::future as said down  and its method "wait_for" to check until your result from database is 1

Comment: but your function performs a single action..i dont understand the use of while loop

Comment: @kunal he painted a picture of his dream code. Think async `yield`

Answer (score 3):

How about [`std::async`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) to compute it in a different thread:

```
int main()
{
    auto r = std::async(std::launch::async, my_fct);

    int result = r.get();    
}
```

Requires C++11 enabled.

Comment: Note that `async` might easily get deprecated in C++14: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3777.pdf

Comment: Interesting, does it have another alternative in C++14?

Comment: None that I know of. The issue is with `~future` where it's unclear whether it should block or detach. See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3773.pdf.

Comment: It won't be deprecated in C++14. It's too late for such a change. N3777 wasn't even a formal motion in Chicago.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to C++11 and as you don't have access to pthreads as you are on Windows then you can use OpenMP. Most C++ compilers on both Unix-like systems and Windows support OpenMP. It is easier to use than pthreads. For example your problem can be coded like:

```
#include <omp.h>
int my_fct() {
    while(1) {
        int result = 1;
        return result;
    }
}
int main()
{
  #pragma omp sections
  {
    #pragma omp section
    {
      my_fct();
    }
    #pragma omp section
    {
      //some other code in parallel to my_fct
    }
  }
}
```

This is one option, take a look at OpenMP tutorials and you may find some other solutions as well.

As suggested in a comment you need to include appropriate compiler flag in order to compile with OpenMP support. It is `/openmp` for MS Visual C++ compiler and `-fopenmp` for GNU C++ compiler. You can find the correct flags for other compilers in their usage manuals.

Comment: Notice that OpenMP requires a special compiler flag to be activated. Most compilers will still compile OpenMP code without this flag, but all OpenMP `#pragma`s will be ignored. This is an easy mistake to make, so be sure your setup is correct.

Comment: @ComicSansMS  Indeed one has to use appropriate compiler flags. I updated the answer with this notice.